# Strange behavior of router events in combination with Observable<boolean> CanDeactivate Guard

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hi,

I've noticed some strange behavior while working on an Angular project. There is a requirement to have reusable auto-save functionality, which is triggered when the user tries to navigate away from a page with a form. We've implemented this using a combination of a guard and a directive which can be applied on a form.

Inside this directive we're making a decision whether to allow the user to navigate away or keep him on the page - if the form is valid we trigger a save callback and let the user go after the callback completes, if the form is not valid we keep the user on the page. It's also important to let the user navigate if they don't interact with the form at all. Translated to code this looks like this:

```js
if (form.dirty) {
    if (form.valid) {
        this.saveCallback().subscribe(this.onNext, this.onError, this.onComplete);
    } else {
        this.guard.disableNavigation();
    }
} else {
    // issue here 
    this.guard.enableNavigation();
}

...

private onNext = () => {
    this.guard.enableNavigation();
};

private onError = () => {
    this.guard.disableNavigation();
};

private onComplete = () => {
    this.formGroupDirective.form.reset();
};
```

In the case that the save callback is triggered it's important to let the user navigate away only after the callback finishes.

The if-else block of code above is run inside a sunscription to router events, which is defined like this:

```js
const navigationEvents$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
);
```

The guard is relatively simple:

```js
export class AutosaveGuard implements CanDeactivate<unknown> {
    private navigationAllowed = new Subject<boolean>();

    canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.navigationAllowed;
    }

    enableNavigation() {
        this.navigationAllowed.next(true);
    }

    disableNavigation() {
        this.navigationAllowed.next(false);
    }
}
```

The strange behavior is that the call marked with the comment issue here, doesn't work - the guard will not let you navigate away. However by chance I've found that if I introduce a call to `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` to the stream definition then it works:

```js
const navigationEvents$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
    observeOn(asyncScheduler)
);
```

**I don't understand why it's working the way it works, and I don't like shipping code I don't fully understand. I'm looking for an answer to the question Why do I have to use `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` in the definition of the navigation events stream for this to work.** There is a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/github/gerangelov/GuardDemo

- When you don't enter any value in the form fields it should let you
  navigate to the other page using the link
- When you enter only one
  field it should prevent you to navigate (form is not valid as both
  inputs are required)
- When you enter a value in both fields it should
  let you navigate after a 400ms delay

If you comment out the observeOn call in the directive the functionality breaks - you can no longer navigate when you don't enter any values (you can still navigate if you enter a value in both)

Comment: It happens because the guard prevents navigation from starting, so `NavigationStart` is never resolved. `observeOn` will re-emit from the source, which is why it works when added. You can reproduce this behaviour by commenting out the `filter` operator on `navigationEvents$`. By switching from a `subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` in your guard and passing `true` as a default value, you can negate the need for `observeOn`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your approach and it almost works, the problem is that if you only fill the first form value and try to navigate then you are not allowed to (which is correct) but then if you fill the second value and attempt to navigate again the save callback will be called (correct) but you are not allowed to navigate away (incorrect). Btw what do you mean by `NavigationStart` is never resolved ? My understanding is that `NavigationStart` is an event that I subscribe to. I see no difference in how often this event is fired when I remove `observeOn`.

Answer (score 1):

well, this code is correct and run when it should:

```
 // issue here 
this.guard.enableNavigation();
```

but the problem came from the way you pass `canDeactivate()` as observable and emit it with a subject.

during `navigationEvents$.subscribe()` you set `this.guard.enableNavigation();` this emits the subject with `true` and **After** that router calls `canDeactivate()` so nothing emits after this call so navigation never happen.

On another hand when you call `this.saveCallback()` and subscribe to it you make a delay and get the router the chance to call `canDeactivate()` and have the subject. after `this.saveCallback()` done, you `next` the subject and everything goes well. you can see this behavior by log the events.

in fact `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` just delayed `this.guard.enableNavigation();` call here and `canDeactivate()` calls before that.

so, you know whats happened there. I can suggest a way that may not be the best practice but it makes a minimum change in your code:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nyuyky?file=src/app/autosave/autosave.guard.ts)

note these changes:

```
  resetNavigation() {
    this.navigationAllowed = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  }
```

and

```
navigationEvents$.subscribe(() => {
  this.guard.resetNavigation();
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution does work and I think I now understand why it worked with `observeOn(asyncScheduler)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to inject the guard into your component, you want the guard to query your component and trigger an asynchronous save if necessary before allowing navigation.

I would create an interface that indicates that a component has a `saveChanges` method that might return a promise:

`support-can-deactivate.ts`:

```js
export interface SupportCanDeactivate {
  saving: boolean; // indicates that saving is in progress
  saveChanges(): Promise<any> | void;
}
```

Then in my form component I'd implement that interface with something like this:

```js
async saveChanges() {
  if (!this.canDeactivate) {
    this.saving = true;
    return timer(2000) // replace this with your actual service call to save changes
      .toPromise()
      .then(r => (this.saving = false));
  }
}
```

In the code of my component I would toggle `canDeactivate` on and off based on whether the form is dirty and touched or not.

Finally in my guard, I would call this method on the component:

`deactivate.guard.ts`:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<void> {
  constructor() {}
  async canDeactivate(component: any) {
    const scd = component as SupportCanDeactivate;
    if (typeof scd.saveChanges === 'function') {
      await scd.saveChanges();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

See [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-da7qxb?file=src/app/guarded/guarded.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not looking for an alternative solution - what I have already works, and there are other events that have to trigger a save not only navigation - that's why I'm using a directive where I can merge together all events for which I have to trigger a save, and handle those using a common subscription. I'm looking for an answer on why I have to use `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` for the navigation to work properly.